# How to differentiate an East Anglian accent from a West Country accent?

Tags: english, accent

I want to understand the East Anglian accents better (Norfolk, Suffolk etc) but can't seem to differentiate it from a West country accent (Devon Somerset, Cornwall) properly.

What linguistics mechanisms are found in the East Anglian accent so that I can properly differentiate them?

Comment: One of the most noticeable differences is that West Country accents are generally rhotic, and East Anglian accents are not.

Comment: @ColinFine I see; so East Anglian is like West Country but they drop their r's?

Comment: I said that that was one of the most noticeable differences, not that it was the only difference ;-) But yes, East Anglia, like most of England and Wales, "drop their r's", but the West Country don't.